# How to put a condition in forming the HTML

Tags: jquery

I am forming the HTML this way

```
   divhtml.append('<section class="cartTable"> \
    <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="totalWrap" align="right"> \
    <tbody> \
    <tr><td align="right" valign="middle" width="50%">Services Charges</td> \
    <td align="right" valign="middle" width="50%">Rs. '+servicecharge+'</td> \
    </tr> \
    <tr><td align="right" valign="middle">Sur Charges</td> \
    <td align="right" valign="middle">Rs. '+surcharge+'</td> \
    </tr> \
    <tr style="border:none;"><td align="right" valign="middle">VAT</td> \
    <td align="right" valign="middle"><strong>Rs. '+VAT+'</strong></td> \
    </tr><tr style="border:none;"><td align="right" valign="middle">Sub Total</td> \
    <td align="right" valign="middle"><strong>Rs. '+subtotal+'</strong></td> \
    </tr> \
    </tbody> \
    </table> \
    <br><br><br> \
    </section>');
```

Is it possible to put a condition in forming the HTML

```
if(something >=0)
{
 <tr><td align="right" valign="middle">Sur Charges</td> \
    <td align="right" valign="middle">Rs. '+surcharge+'</td> \
    </tr> \

}
```

Means i want to have this printed only once .

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
var html = '<section class="cartTable"> 
    <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="totalWrap" align="right"> 
    <tbody> 
    <tr><td align="right" valign="middle" width="50%">Services Charges</td> 
    <td align="right" valign="middle" width="50%">Rs. '+servicecharge+'</td> 
    </tr> ';

if(something >=0)
{
    html += '<tr><td align="right" valign="middle">Sur Charges</td> 
    <td align="right" valign="middle">Rs. '+surcharge+'</td> 
    </tr>';
}
   html += '<tr style="border:none;"><td align="right" valign="middle">VAT</td> 
    <td align="right" valign="middle"><strong>Rs. '+VAT+'</strong></td> 
    </tr><tr style="border:none;"><td align="right" valign="middle">Sub Total</td> 
    <td align="right" valign="middle"><strong>Rs. '+subtotal+'</strong></td> 
    </tr> 
    </tbody> 
    </table> 
    <br><br><br> 
    </section>';
divhtml.append(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your html to do that with jQuery or to use a template engine.

With jQuery you can do :

```
divhtml.append('<div>Some content</div>');

if (foo > 0) {
    divhtml.append('<div>Some conditional content</div>');
}

divhtml.append('<div>Some content</div>');
```

That's the main idea, of course it's better to store the html as a string in a var and to call append only once.

Answer (score 0):

Use the js only:

```
  var html = "<div> first part before the condition"
  if (something >= 0) {
    html += "condition part";
  }
  html += "end part of the html";
  // then using jquery to apeend html to the jquery object's DOM
  $divhtml.append(html);
```

You can also use some template library like handlebars http://handlebarsjs.com/:

```
  <div>
    {{#if condition}}
       <h1>shows only something >= 0</h1>
    {{/if}}
  </div>


  html = Template.Sometemplate({condition:something >= 0});
  $divhtml.append(html);
```